# Do we have alternative of force:hasRecordId for LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

In looking at this [page](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.reference_configuration_tags) of the LWC developer guide, I have not found any details around this.

Clearly to get an LWC working for a record page you can use target for `RecordPage` as below, making this component available to Account Page. But I need the `recordId` as well

```
<targets>
    <target>lightning__AppPage</target>
    <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
    <target>lightning__HomePage</target>
</targets>
```

What is required in order to make the record ID available to my component?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can [get the recordId](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.use_record_context) by creating a property with `@api recordId;`.

Example:

```
// testClass.js
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';
export default class TestClass extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;
}
```